# Get all permutations without replacement?

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

I'd like to get all the permutations of a list but without any repetitions, regardless of ordering. It's kind of hard to describe so I'll give an example. I'd really like to know the name  of this operation because I use it all the time. Also a simple way to achieve this in python would really help me out. Thanks!

e.g

```
['foo', 'bar', 'la']

==>

['foo', 'bar']
['foo', 'la']
['ba', 'la']
```

Comment: This is not permutations, this is combination without repetition. Also, what "replacement"?

Comment: Ok that nugget of wisdom is pretty much what i was looking for thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations(['foo', 'bar', 'la'], 2))
[('foo', 'bar'), ('foo', 'la'), ('bar', 'la')]
```